# Get the indexes for the top 3 values from a dataframe row (using a fast implementation)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the indexes for the 3 highest values for each row in a pandas dataframe.
Right now I am using

```
top3df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nlargest(3).index), axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, this function is quite costly and runs on my example dataset of 2,000,000rows x 80columns for about 30 minutes.
Is there any faster way?

Comment: Kindly share sample data with expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with axis=1, use `[:,::-1]` to reverse the order of the sort and then `[:,:3]` to select the first 3 columns of the array. Then recreate the dataframe

```
#input
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,100).reshape(10, 10), 
                  columns=list('abcdefghij'))

# sort
top3 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1)[:, ::-1][:,:3])
print(top3)
    0   1   2
0  74  72  56
1  96  93  81
2  90  90  69
3  97  79  62
4  94  78  64
5  85  71  63
6  99  91  80
7  96  95  61
8  91  90  74
9  88  60  56
```

EDIT: OP changed the question to extract the columns' names of the top 3 values per row, that can be done with `argsort` and slicing the columns names:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(df.columns.to_numpy()
                     [np.argsort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)][:, -1:-4:-1]))
```

Comment: `np.sort(df, axis=1)[:,-1:-4:-1]` might perform better but less readable.

Comment: Out of curiosity I just tested the both versions using a dataframe of the same size as OP and ipython's `%timeit` magic method and slicing once or twice is basically the same in terms of performance. Although the twice sliced version did have a smaller std. dev. 18.7ms vs 49.7ms.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I also need x.nlargest(3).index. Therefore, this will not work for me. My fault in the description, I updated it.

Comment: @Andreas then you can use `argsort` and slice the columns' names like this `df.columns.to_numpy()[np.argsort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)]`